# How to set cursor hotspot with TailwindCSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, mouse-cursor

I want to use a custom image for my cursor with tailwind, however I need to set the hotspot to the center of the image, and I can't figure out how to properly add coordinates to specify where the hotspot should go.

Is this possible?

Note: I don't want to do this in the theme as I will change the cursor based on user input, and will also need to change the hotspot.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/cursor

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using an arbitrary css value.

`[cursor:url(/cursor/circle-5px-opt.svg)_3_3,pointer]`

Make sure that the coordinates are separated with underscores instead of whitespace otherwise it won't work.

[Arbitrary Properties](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties)

[Whitespace](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#handling-whitespace)